# Point values obtained from rasters with different extent, projection and resolution

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, point, resolution

I am trying to predict a species' distribution. I am fairly new to GIS, so apologies if I am talking nonsense.

I gathered various geo-referenced environmental data from different databases. The files come in slightly varying extents (global scale), most have WGS84 projection but some do not, and generally the resolution varies between 250m to 1km. I have around 500k occurrence points and intended to sample 500k points randomly as background data. I read that reprojecting rasters should be avoided at all costs and instead the spatial points should be reprojected to the CRS of the particular raster file before extracting values.

I just started reading the introduction to species distribution models by Robert J. Hijmans and Jane Elith who note *"For any particular study the layers should all have the same spatial extent, resolution, origin, and projection."*. I was a bit surprised to read this as I did not see any harm in extracting point values from different resolutions, extents and projections (as long as points are reprojected).

I hope there are more experienced GIS modelers here that could enlighten me whether I was too naive in simply extracting point values from all these different databases without worrying about harmonizing all the rasters to the same extent, resolution and projection.

Comment: The projection-thing is kind of outdated, since at small scales (global/nationwide coverage) occuring transformation errors between different CRS are negligible. The worst accuracy I came across until today was between some Ukranian CRS and WGS 84 (about 7 m error). Nowadays at least QGIS can easily work with layers which are using different CRS. Still, if you want to cover the whole globe, you will end up using either EPSG 4326 or 3857. The resolution issue on the other hand is important - though from a scientific background - you shouldn't compare data with 1 km resolution to 250 m res.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Could you elaborate on why different resolutions are problematic? I understand that I should not compare the entire rasters, but if in the end I use point estimates why is the resolution important (besides the different accuracy of the estimate)

Comment: This is very broad topic. And the answer to such topic is "It depends on many things.". Warping all rasters to WGS84 lat-long using nearest neighbour might be just fine, if it meets your accuracy expectations and we talk about area independent values like vegetation index or land use. Then you can use for example QGIS software with point sampling tool and run it once on all rasters and done. Generally speaking translating points for each different CRS of rasters and sampling separately is way better idea.

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand correctly, but currently I do not stack any of the rasters but simply iterate over them individually (in R) and extract the point values. Is the different resolution problematic in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are perfectly oriented. The phrase that surprises you only apply if you want to operate the rasters between them. In your case, do not reproject any raster.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your expertise!